# How to find $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^{\sqrt{x}}$ using L'Hospital's Rule.

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to find $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^{\sqrt{x}}$ using L'Hospital's Rule. I've differentiate the function, but it doesn't seem like that has helped at all.

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^{\sqrt{x}} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} x^{\sqrt{x}} (\frac{\ln(x)}{2\sqrt{x}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})$$

$$\frac{d}{dx} y = \frac{d}{dx} \ln(x^{\sqrt{x}}) \to \frac{1}{y} \cdot y'= \sqrt{x}\ln(x) \to y' = y(\frac{\ln(x)}{2\sqrt{x}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}) \to y' = x^{\sqrt{x}} (\frac{\ln(x)}{2\sqrt{x}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})$$

How can I figure out what this limit represents?

Comment: You don't differentiate the function directly. L'Hopital's Rule can only be used on expressions of the from $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, where either both $f$ and $g$ go to $0$, or both go to $\pm\infty$. So first you need to convert $x^{\sqrt{x}}$ into such an expression. HINT: use the fact that (i) $a^b = e^{b\ln(a)}$; and (ii) the exponential function is continuous, so $\lim e^{g(x)} = e^{\lim(g(x))}$. And *then* you'll need to do some more work before you can apply L'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin In fact, application of LHR for $\frac fg$ when $g\to \infty$ does not require that $f\to \infty$.  In fact the limit $\lim f$ need not even exist.

Comment: @MarkViola: True; though if $|f(x)|$ is eventually bounded, then you don't need to invoke the Rule at all to get the answer.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, of course.  But it's possible that computing the limit of $f$ is more challenging (if it exists) than computing the limit of $f'$.

Comment: Instead of using l'Hopital, consider that $0=\lim_{y\to \infty} (-2\ln \sqrt y)/\sqrt y =$ $=\lim_{x\to 0^+} -2\ln (1/\sqrt x))/(1/\sqrt x) =$ $\lim_{x\to 0^+}(\sqrt x)\ln x=$ $\lim_{x\to \infty}\ln (x^{\sqrt x}).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note first that
$$\lim_{x\to 0+} x^x = \exp\left(\lim_{x\to 0^+} x \log x\right) = \exp\left(\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\log x}{x^{-1}}\right) = \exp\left(-\lim_{x\to 0^+} x\right) = 1.
$$
by (continuity and) l'Hopital's rule. Thus
$$\lim_{x\to 0+} x^{\sqrt{x}} = \lim_{x\to 0^+} x^{2x} = 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+}\ln{x^{\sqrt{x}}}=
\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sqrt{x}\ln{x}=
\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln{x}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}\stackrel{\text{L'H}}{=}\\
\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\left(\ln{x}\right)'}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)'}=
\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^3}}}=
-2\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sqrt{x}=-2\cdot 0=0.\\
\ln{x^{\sqrt{x}}}\xrightarrow{x\rightarrow 0^+}0\implies
x^{\sqrt{x}}\xrightarrow{x\rightarrow 0^+}1.
$$
Therefore:

$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^{\sqrt{x}}=1.
$$

I used the simple fact that if the logarithm of a function of x ($f(x)=x^{\sqrt{x}}$) approaches 0 as x goes to 0 from the right ($\lim_{x\to 0^+}\ln{f(x)}=0$), $f(x)$ must approach $1$ because only the logarithm of a quantity that's getting closer to 1 is getting closer to 0.

Comment: I thought $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = \frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}}{x}$?

Comment: Well, algebraically it's the same thing, the only difference is that you lost a minus sign somewhere: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate+1%2Fsqrt(x) There has to be a minus sign in front of the result that you get.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = x^\sqrt x$. 
Then $\ln f(x) = \sqrt x \ \ln(x) = \dfrac{\ln x}{x^{-\frac 12}}$.

Then 
$\dfrac{(\ln x)'}{\left( \dfrac{1}{\sqrt x} \right)'}
=\dfrac{x^{-1}}{\frac 12 x^{-\frac 32}} = \sqrt x \to 0 \ \text{as} \ x \to 0^+$.

It follows that $f(x) \to e^0 = 1$ as $x \to 0^+$.

Answer (score 1):

You can transform it to a well-known limit:
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^{\sqrt{x}}=\lim_{x \to 0^+} [(\sqrt{x})^2]^{\sqrt{x}}=\lim_{x \to 0^+} [(\sqrt{x})^{\sqrt{x}}]^2=\lim_{t \to 0^+} [t^t]^2=\left[\lim_{t \to 0^+} t^t\right]^2=1^2=1.$$
For  $\lim_\limits{t \to 0^+} t^t=1$, refer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213333/how-to-prove-lim-x-to-0xx-1) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769644/evaluate-lim-x-rightarrow-0-xx).